# Django, autogenerate one-to-many tables, and database structure

Tags: database, django, one-to-many

I am using django for a website where I have a database with users, people, locations, items and so on. Know i find that I need some extra information that requires one-to-many relations like Aliases for most of these tables.

Should I (1) create a common alias table for all of these by using the content type framework (will probably end up with billions of rows), or should I (2) create a alias table for each of these. If the latter one, how do I auto-create one-to-many table like this by just adding a single line like this

"alias = Ailias()"

in each model. I`m sure I saw an app doing something like that way a while ago, I think is was a reversion app of some kind. Even if the second method is not suited i would love tho understand how to do it. I do not know what to search after to find an explanation of this.

I plan to add Haystack with Solr to this, so method 2 might add much extra work there. But I do not have much experience with it jet, so I might be wrong.

PS: ended up wih method one.

Answer (score 0):

Manage to do what I wanted in method 2, easily generate one-to-many fields. Not sure if this is the easiest way, or the best way. If someone has a better way of doing it, I would love to learn it. I am a long way from a django expert, so I might have meddled with some unnecessary complex stuff to do what I wanted.

This example creates an easy way of adding a one-to-many alias relationship.

Alias Managers

```
class AliasManagerDescriptor(object):
def __init__(self, model,fkName):
    self.model = model
    self.fkName = fkName

def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    if instance is None:
        return AliasManager(self.model,self.fkName)
    return AliasManager(self.model, self.fkName, instance)

class AliasManager(models.Manager):
def __init__(self, model,fkName, instance=None):
    super(AliasManager, self).__init__()
    self.model = model
    self.instance = instance
    #Name of FK linking this model to linked model
    self.fkName=fkName

def get_query_set(self):
    """
    Get query set, or only get instances from this model that is linked
    to the chosen instance from the linked model if one is chosen
    """
    if self.instance is None:
        return super(AliasManager, self).get_query_set()

    if isinstance(self.instance._meta.pk, models.OneToOneField):
        #TODO: Checkif this part works, not checked
        filter = {self.instance._meta.pk.name+"_id":self.instance.pk}
    else:
        filter = {self.fkName: self.instance.pk}
    return super(AliasManager, self).get_query_set().filter(**filter)

def create(self,**kwargs):
    """
    Create alias instances. If FK is not given then it is automatically set
    to the chosen instance from the linked model
    """
    if self.fkName not in kwargs:
        kwargs[self.fkName]=self.instance
    print kwargs
    super(AliasManager, self).create(**kwargs)
```

Alias Models

```
class Alias(object):

def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
    self.manager_name = name
    aliasModel = self.create_alias_model(cls)
    descriptor = AliasManagerDescriptor(aliasModel,cls._meta.object_name.lower())
    setattr(cls, self.manager_name, descriptor)

def create_alias_model(self, model):
    """
    Creates a alias model to associate with the model provided.
    """
    attrs = {
             #'id': models.AutoField(primary_key=True),
             "name": models.CharField(max_length=255),

             #Not sure which to use of the two next methods
             model._meta.object_name.lower(): models.ForeignKey(model),
             #model._meta.object_name.lower(): AliasObjectDescriptor(model),

             '__unicode__': lambda self: u'%s' % self.name,
             '__module__': model.__module__
             }
    attrs.update(Meta=type('Meta', (), self.get_meta_options(model)))
    name = '%s_alias' % model._meta.object_name
    return type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)

def get_meta_options(self, model):
    """
    Returns a dictionary of fields that will be added to
    the Meta inner class.
    """
    return {
    }


"""class AliasObjectDescriptor(object):
def __init__(self, model):
    self.model = model

def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    values = (getattr(instance, f.attname) for f in self.model._meta.fields)
    return self.model(*values)"""
```

Person Model - Only need to add "alias = Alias()" to a model to add a one-to-many alias field.

```
class Person(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
age = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)

alias = Alias()
```

Now you I can do something like this:

```
per = Person(name="Per",age=99)
per.save()
per.alias.create(name="Mr.P")
per_alias = per.alias.all().values_list("name",flat=True)
```